# Azure Function can not download Managed dependency for PowerShell Core in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell, azureportal, azure-function-app

I have 4 function apps. Only one function app will successfully run a function, even if they are the same function. The other 3 functions either will not run or give me a managed Dependency download error as follows:

```
> 2019-09-16T14:37:51.707 [Error] Executed
> 'Functions.UiPath_New_User_Email' (Failed,
> Id=557d0895-1765-4558-9dc6-2346ddaa1841) Result: Failure Exception:
> Fail to install FunctionApp dependencies. Error: 'Fail to create
> FunctionApp dependencies destination path
> 'D:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\190916143602765.r'. Please make sure
> you have write access to this location. Error 'There is not enough
> space on the disk :
> 'D:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\190916143602765.ri''. ' Stack: at
> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.DependencyManagement.DependencyManager.WaitOnDependencyInstallationTask()
> in
> C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\DependencyManagement\DependencyManager.cs:line
> 239 at
> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.DependencyManagement.DependencyManager.WaitForDependenciesAvailability(Func`1
> getLogger) in
> C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\DependencyManagement\DependencyManager.cs:line
> 145 at
> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.RequestProcessor.ProcessInvocationRequest(StreamingMessage
> request) in
> C:\projects\azure-functions-powershell-worker\src\RequestProcessor.cs:line
> 233
```

Comment: Did you create it on the portal or  creat on the Visual Studio?

Comment: If you create it on the portal, you need to create a file on the portal first to load the dependency of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from the error that these are PowerShell functions.  The error is around the ["managed dependencies" feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management) which will pull in modules you define for you.

Can you confirm the requirements.psd1 is identical for all apps?  If so may be worth opening an issue [here](https://github.com/azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker) as well and include the names of the function apps if you can.